# Emacs Psychotherapist: Where can I find the code?

Tags: c, emacs

I'd like to port the Emacs Psychotherapist to C :) but I would like to know where I can find the source code. What I am afraid of is that it is written in Lisp. If it is I think I will be out of luck porting it to C unless someone has already done it.

Any pointers would be appreciated (pun not intended!)

Comment: So you think you'll be successful porting it only if someone else has already done it? Nice.

Comment: Looking the LISP, porting it to C is going to be tough. You could always first invoke http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_Tenth_Rule once that's done, the rest of the port should be easy. ;-)

Comment: why port?  why not integrate whatever you have with the lisp doctor?

Comment: @Tiberiu Ana, have a look at the lisp, it is not a trivial task porting that to C, it actually would be quite difficult, porting from C++/C on platform to another would be quite easy on the other hand

Comment: @Cheeso, how would I go about doing that. I'd like to integrate it with C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is in Emacs is a variant of [Eliza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA), so you might want to start looking there. That link lists many places to get different versions of the source.

Porting from Lisp to C is definitely doable, but there is a sufficiently different approach in those languages to make it difficult.

Here is one version of the [good doctor](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=10353&lngWId=3), written in C++. Or there is a [general description of how it works](http://www.sourcecodesworld.com/articles/How-to-build-Eliza-Chatterbot.asp).

Eliza is the only doctor with more lives than Doctor Who!

Answer (score 16):

For this kind of thing, it's handy to know about

```
M-x find-function doctor
```

Answer (score 10):

[It's in emacs-lisp.](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/emacs/lisp/play/doctor.el?root=emacs&view=markup)

Just because it's been some time since I fired up the doctor:

```
I am the psychotherapist.  Please, describe your problems.  Each time you are
finished talking, type RET twice.

Where is your source code?

Why do you say 
where is my source code?
```